# Check contents of a column in mongodb / python

Tags: python, mongodb

I have a mongodb collection of Craigslist listings imported from a csv. It has three fields (all strings) of titles, prices, and dates listed. Some elements in the prices fields though are not strings consisting of only digits. Some elements in the prices field have a description of the listing (instead of "400" it's " Gtx Quadro blah blah blah...")

Is there a way to loop through the whole prices column and check the first element in that string? If the first element in the string is not a digit, the I would like the whole listing (title, price, date listed) to be deleted.

Would this be a query written in mongodb compass or a script written in my python script that imports the csv to my mongodb collection?

Bonus, is there a way to add a "build trigger" to the query/script to run every time.the collection is re populated with a new csv every hour?

Comment: Are the values in the `prices` column stored as strings? (E.g., "400" vs 400 vs 400.0). If they're stored as integers or non strings you can search for non integer values you can use the `$type` operator. If everything in the column is stored as a string you can use regex matching to find invalid prices (`$regex` operator)

Comment: Yes they are stored as strings. Is there a way in mongodb or python to change the value after they are uploaded. And if it gives me an error because a letter S cannot be a interfer to find what listing gave the error and delete the whole listing?

Comment: If you have control over the python script that is importing the data, I'd filter out the non-integer prices there.   This also avoids the whole "build trigger" problem.

Comment: That what I tried. d is a list that contains titles, prices, and dates listed (d=[titles,prices, dates]). before I send d to get formatted to .csv file, I run a loop checking the contents of prices (for i in d[1]). In the loop i run a if condtion. The condition is checking if the first element in the string i (i[0]) is not a digit(if not i[0].isdigit() ). If i get false (that means the first element in i is not a digit) I set i=0.

Comment: It works. I  print out i after the check and print out the list of prices. Any price that had that did not have a digit in its first element ('September 1...") gets set to 0. although, when I check my csv file, The change has not took effect. Where i print out 0, i get the original incorrect contents. For example, the first string in the prices lists is "Sept 3 AMD...". after I run the check and print out the prices list again, that string is set to 0.

Comment: Although, when i check the CSV and MongoDB the invalid string is back in its place.

Answer (score 0):

found out how to solve it. the method that parses the whole title an assigns sections as title, price, and date posted i had to make a check after price is initialized.

```
 if not price[:1].isdigit():
            price = "0"
        int(price)
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you've posted an answer - but just in case you wanted another potential solution I'll post an answer as well.

I definitely advocate for catching any invalid documents in your import prior to inserting them into the db, but this may help you clean up the current db. I don't know what the documents in your collection look like so I make a couple of assumptions here, if you post an example valid and an invalid document that would help.

Assuming the invalid prices are stored as strings in your collection - meaning an invalid document looks like:

```
{"_id": ObjectId("51a6547f31909d7260db9a62"), "title": "My item", "price": "Hello there", "date": 1567565245}
```

OR

```
{"_id": ObjectId("51a6547f31909d7260db9a62"), "title": "My item", "price": "400", "date": 1567565245}
```

Whereas a valid document contains something like `"price": 400`, then you can use a `deleteMany` command (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.deleteMany/) matching all documents with a string price field (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/) to purge your database of any invalid documents. In the Mongo shell:

```
db.collection.deleteMany({price: {$type: 2}})
```

OR in Python

```
import pymongo
db = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}'.format(username, password, host, port, db_name)).craigslist # or whatever the name of your db is
result = db.collection_name.delete_many({"price": {"$type": 2}}) # substitute collection_name with the name of the collection these docs are stored in
print("Deleted", result.deleted_count, "documents with invalid prices")
```

However, if all your prices are meant stored as strings like `"price": "$400"` or `"price": "400"` then you can use a regular expression to delete non-matches.

In the Mongo Shell:

```
db.collection.deleteMany({price: {$not: /^\$?\d+\.?\d{0,2}$/}})
```

In Python:

```
import pymongo
import re
db = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}'.format(username, password, host, port, db_name)).craigslist
result = db.collection_name.delete_many({"price": {"$not": re.compile(r"^\$?\d+\.?\d{0,2}$")}}) # substitute collection_name with the name of the collection these docs are stored in
print("Deleted", result.deleted_count, "documents with invalid prices")
```